# Multiple GPU card problems

Tags: gpu

I have two GPU cards in my machine. I had a GTX 980 Ti and I recently added a GTX 1070. My render times have more than doubled, however when I go back to look at my PNG's, I notice that they don't line up. Every other frame is slightly off in "space" so when the PNG's are run together or if I put them through the video sequence editor, it makes my object shake or slightly move back and forth. Almost like a heat wave effect. Not sure what to do, or if anyone else has seen this.

Comment: I hope the render times have more than halved..

Comment: I think the new 1000 series Nvidia GPUs are not yet fully supported in Blender. Some issues are to be expected

Comment: Are you on Windows 10?

Comment: I am indeed. I'm using Windows 10 Pro. I have an Intel i7-6700k CPU @ 4 Ghz. The OS is 64 Bit. I have the GTX 1070 in my primary slot and the GTX 980Ti CLASSIFIED in the secondary. These are not SLI. I was wondering if it was because the new Kernel isn't out yet for the 1070, but not sure.

Comment: Sergej Sharybin in one of the latest Blender Cloud Podcasts mentioned that there is still issues with cards that require Cuda Toolkit version 8 (in essence, with the 10xx series cards). The problem is that the Toolkit 8 is still in beta. When using it for compiling Blender, there's speed regressions on older cards. So at the moment what they do is this: they compile the cycles kernels for "old" architectures with Toolkit 7.5, and the kernel for 10xx cards with the Toolkit 8 beta. Now if there's a bug in that one, it would explain your issue. Please file a report: https://developer.blender.org/

Comment: Pascal cards are fully supported in 2.78, you should test it if the problems are gone, or report them as a bug report for 2.78 RC2.

Answer (score -1):

Problems like this might happen when using different devices to render one frame. That's why render farms have always one type of GPU and/or CPU letting render one frame. If its an animation, lets say frame 1-100, just open Blender 2 times, let one instance of Blender render with one GPU the first half (frame 1-49) and the other instance with the other GPU the other half (frame 50-100).

I never used 2 GPUs though, i dont know if this will work perfectly. But i think so.

Comment: If the scene will render correctly on either of those cards, it should render correctly on both of them. Can you back up your arguments? If it's not working, it is probably a driver or cuda kernel issue and will effect the single card in the same way.

Comment: I assumed it is working properly if he uses only one card.
I red multiple times of people who have issues using 2 different cards.

Also, if you render an image on one card and compare the result with another, different card, the result will never be 100% the same. Even if the other card is the same type of card. Thats just not possible, you cant have 2 exact equal peaces of hardware. And therefore not same results. (im talking about very little to non visible differences, not what the OP is experiencing)

Comment: I've used multi GPU machines to render with no issues at all, even when mixing GPU with different CUDA processors.

Comment: Nice to hear.

Did you have to do anything special? Some special settings or drivers?
I once thought about getting a second gpu (from nvidia, i only have a amd 280x, which you still cant use properly in Blender... :'(     ). This is where i red about this problems.

Comment: @Reaper Don't believe things on internet, even if they are same in multiple instances. There are many people thinking the earth is flat and you might read it several times. The code running on the hardware is deterministic. It will produce the same result provided the same input. If the sobol noise that Cycles uses get's the same seed, it will produce 100% same results even on different hardware (running the same CUDA kernel).